# How to set max pinch zoom in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, pinchzoom, mpandroidchart

I m coding a line chart using MPAndroidChart, my code works without any error but pinch zooming goes to infinity, because of that in some devices CPU has 100%. How can i restrict max pinch zoom?

Answer (score 11):

The mpandroidhchart developer implemented this in this commit:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/commit/ba152072a6a7adbf8e9e166904798219c1200172

But I'm still waiting for a new release version. Further, you just need to call

```
chart.getViewPortHandler().setMaximumScaleX(2f);
chart.getViewPortHandler().setMaximumScaleY(2f);
```

*And this will limit the zoom in factor 2*

Answer (score 0):

setScaleMinima(2f, 1f)

Setting scale min to 0f same as zoom out too infinity. 1f would allow you to adjust zoom so you can see the whole graph.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AlexBalio but that doesn't fix my problem. I need a method to restrict zoom, for ex user shouldn't zoom after 3x.. but MPAndroidChart doesn't have setMaxZoom(float f,..) unfortunality. Do you have any other advice to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What I found helpful and ended up using was setting the visible range which also stops the zoom to not go beyond the max or min values that you set. For example:

```
    chart.setVisibleYRangeMinimum(1f, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(5f)
```